# How can I see MSMQ in local Computer Management interface?

Tags: msmq

I'm trying to debug an application that uses Microsoft Message Queuing (MSMQ). I can debug the queues on my development server using a remote desktop connection, but can't repeat the process on my local desktop. I would prefer to use an application on my local desktop if possible.

My development server is running Windows Server 2003 R2 Enterprise Edition. My local machine is running Windows 7 Professional Edition.

To debug the queues using a remote desktop connection (see first screenshot):

1. Connect remotely as DEV\admin_me to the desktop of my development server (DEVSERVER).
2. Run `compmgmt.msc`.
3. Navigate to 'Computer Management (Local) > Services and Applications > Message Queueing > Private Queues' to see the two private queues used by my application.

[image: Message Queueing management is possible over a remote desktop connection.]

To repeat the process on my local desktop (see second screenshot):

1. Run `runas /user:DEV\admin_me "mmc compmgmt.msc /computer:\\DEVSERVER"`. *(Use runas because my local desktop account is DEV\me, not admin).*
2. Try to navigate to 'Computer Management (DEVSERVER) > Services and Applications > Message Queueing', but it is not visible.

[image: Message Queueing management is not possible on the local desktop.]

Am I missing something, or is using a remote desktop connection the only way?

Comment: Do you have MSMQ installed? I assume not. You won't have the DLL installed that Computer Management loads to expose MSMQ.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As suggested by [John Breakwell's comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/393921/how-can-i-see-msmq-in-local-computer-management-interface#comment418184_393921), MSMQ was not installed on my local machine. I followed these steps to enable management of a remote MSMQ application from my local machine

**Install MSMQ**

At a command prompt, run the command `OptionalFeatures` to open the 'Windows Features' dialog.

In the feature tree of the dialog, Check the top-level feature 'Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) Server'. This also checks the sub-feature 'Microsoft MessageQueue (MSMQ) Server Core'. The dialog should look like this:

[image: Check the feature 'Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) Server to install MSMQ support.]

Press OK.

Windows displays a dialog to say *"Please wait while Windows makes changes to features. This might take several minutes."* Wait until the dialog disappears.

[image: Wait until the 'please wait' dialog disappears to check that the fix has worked.]

**Verify the fix**

Run the command to compmgmt.msc locally:

```
runas /user:DEV\admin_me "mmc compmgmt.msc /computer:\\DEVSERVER"
```

Navigate to 'Computer Management (Local) > Services and Applications > Message Queueing > Private Queues' and verify that the two private queues used by my application are visible.

[image]